# npm run build error. what i'm doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack

I'm trying to run npm script **build**. And getting an error 
`Unknown argument: mode
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! App@0.0.0 build:`webpack --mode production
`npm ERR! Exit status 1`.

npm script:
`webpack --mode production`

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You probably have an old version of webpack installed globally.

Comment: It works for me. I have installed new version of webpack.